# How to collapse all divs with change of a tab in jQuery Tabs UI?

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using several WordPress loops and jQuery UI Tabs that result in the Main tabs and entry-content div markup below. The WordPress loops generate the "entry-post" markup in each tab div, but I'm not showing the php, as the resulting html markup in each tab div is the important part.

I'm also using a bit of jQuery to independently expand/collapse each entry-content div:

```
$(".entry-content").hide();
$(".entry-title").click(function() {
$(this).parent().children(".entry-content").slideToggle(500); });
```

What I've found is that each of the entry-content divs keeps their expanded state when switching tabs, i.e. if some of the entry-content divs are expanded in tabone and I switch to tabtwo and then back to tabone, they're still expanded in tabone.

What I need to do is collapse all the entry-content divs in a tab when a tab is changed. Below is the tab init and also the fx to change the tabs.

What do I need to add to this function to collapse all the entry-content divs when a tab is changed?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var $tabs= $("#tabs").tabs(); 
});
$(function() {
$('#tabs').tabs({
fx: { opacity:'toggle' }
});
});
```

**Main tabs and entry-content div markup:**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabone">tabone</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabtwo">tabtwo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabthree">tabthree</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabone">

<div class="entry-post">
<h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
<div class="entry-content">Lorem ipsum...  
</div></div>

<div class="entry-post">
<h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
<div class="entry-content">Lorem ipsum...  
</div></div>

<div class="entry-post">
<h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
<div class="entry-content">Lorem ipsum...  
</div></div>
    </div>

    <div id="tabtwo">

<div class="entry-post">
<h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
<div class="entry-content">Lorem ipsum...  
</div></div>

<div class="entry-post">
<h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
<div class="entry-content">Lorem ipsum...  
</div></div>

<div class="entry-post">
<h1 class="entry-title">Title</h1>
<div class="entry-content">Lorem ipsum...  
</div></div>
    </div>

    <div id="tabthree">

....

</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should collapse all `.entry-content` divs whenever a new tab is selected:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var $tabs= $("#tabs").tabs({
        fx : { 
            opacity: 'toggle' 
        },
        select : function(event, ui) {
            $(".entry-content").hide();                
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks. Nice action of collapsing the divs and then going right into the tab change fx. I'm still learning jQuery, but I can see some of how this works.

Comment: I'm glad it helps. I'm also relatively new to jQuery, but once you get the hang of it, everything just "clicks" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.post [name^="entry-title"]").hide();
```

should do what you're wanting when attached next to your fx.

or:

```
$("#tabs a").click(function () {
  $("div.post [name^="entry-title"]").hide();
});
```

Comment: Looks like it should work; how would this be integrated into the one function above? (code simplified above)

Comment: `$(function() {
  $('#tabs').tabs({
    $("div.post [name^="entry-title"]").hide();
    fx: { opacity:'toggle' }
  });
});`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand you're question completely. But if you wan't to check whether the tab is triggered or not, try use this:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  show: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Simplified how you could collapse all divs with class "entry-post", whenever the tab is showed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
    show: function(){
      $('.entry-post').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I simplified my code above; how would that be integrated into the one tab function above that changes the tabs?

Comment: See my answer now, i wrote a quick example. Think that could do the work, however i'm still not sure why you need this.

Comment: That example kills all the entry-content divs and none of them show. What I want to do is on a tab change collapse all the divs in that tab, not hide them.

Comment: My mistake. You actually want exactly this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ - if yes, see the code. I think you maybe miss the styles? .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide { display: none !important; }

Comment: Yes, I know; I am using jQuery Tabs UI. No, I'm not missing the style sheet.

Comment: I made this example, is that not exactly what you want? If not, then describe you're problem again. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtWHs/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a jQuery expert, so here's straight javascript. Might at least help solve the problem...
Since you don't care what tab a div is on (since all divs should be hidden when a tab is changed) you could simply hide all divs on the page every time a tab is changed, regardless of what tab it's on.

```
var divList = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-content");
for(var divitem in divList){
  divitem.style.display = "none";
}
```

I wish my jQuery was stronger so I could give it in that, but it may help...

Edit:
Just looking at what your example code, I guess something like this in jQuery:

```
$("#tabs a").click(function() { $(".entry-content").hide(); });
```

Something that closes all entry-content class divs when any tab is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make use of the existing jquery UI tabs library and this will solve a lot of your problems.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Using this will allow you to make a better association between your list items and the divs they are controlling. Add the reference in your header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

or download it and remove what you don't need. Add the following to your CSS

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

and change your references so they are in keeping with the jqueryUI specification

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">tabone</a></li>
```

and then the div ids to match

```
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <div class="entry-post">
```

this should make the association. You can then add the controlling behaviour so it should read

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function() {
            $('#tabs').tabs();
        });
```

and that will do away with the need to store the array of divs

you can then bind a function to the tabselect event which will hide the divs you want to collapse

```
$('#tabs').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
            $('#tabs').children().not(ui.panel).children().children(".entry-content").hide();
        });
```

your code should then read:

```
<head>
<title>Collapse Divs</title>
<style type="text/css">

    .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
        display: none !important;
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function() {
            $('#tabs').tabs();
        });

        $('#tabs').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
            $('#tabs').children().not(ui.panel).children().children(".entry-content").hide();
        });

        $(".entry-content").hide();

        $(".entry-title").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().children(".entry-content").slideToggle(500); 
            });

});
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">tabone</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">tabtwo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">tabthree</a></li>
    </ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
    <div class="entry-post">
...
    <h1 class="entry-title">Title 3.3</h1>
        <div class="entry-content">Lorem ipsum...</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: I'm already using the Tabs UI, libraries and CSS. This looks good, but it collapses a div right after expanding it, rather than waiting for a tab change, i.e. the divs bounce open and closed.

Comment: really? It shouldn't do. I have tested it on Firefox, Chrome and Safari. The clicking of the entry-title should only be calling the click listener for those and toggling. The .not(ui.panel) reference in the tabsselect should also mean that you can click on the active tab and it shouldn't affect the divs. what browser are you using?